# PHP echo file contents

Tags: php, file, pdf

I have a pdf file which is located off my webpage's root. I want to serve a file in `../cvs` to my users using php.

Here is the code I have sofar:

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');

$file = file_get_contents('/home/eamorr/sites/eios.com/www/cvs/'.$cv);
echo $file;
```

But when I call this php page, nothing gets printed! I'd like to simply serve the pdf file stored whose name is in `$cv` (e.g. `$cv = 'xyz.pdf'`).

The ajax response to this PHP page returns the text of the pdf (gobbldy-gook!), but I want the file, not the gobbldy-gook!

I hope this makes sense.

Many thanks in advance,

---

Here's the AJAX I'm using

```
$('#getCurrentCV').click(function(){
    var params={
        type: "POST",
        url: "./ajax/getCV.php",
        data: "",
        success: function(msg){
            //msg is gobbldy-gook!
        },
        error: function(){

        }
    };
    var result=$.ajax(params).responseText;
});
```

I'd like the user to be prompted to download the file.

Comment: Does the file exist? Is error reporting turned on?

Comment: What do you mean by "stored as `$cv`"? What is `$cv`?

Comment: $cv is a file called xyz.pdf and it exists in /home/eamorr/sites/eios.com/www/cvs/xyz.pdf

Comment: Does the file exist? Is error reporting turned on?

Comment: The file exists. No errors are being thrown as the file is read, but returned to the AJAX request as gobbldy-gook.

Comment: Explain what you're talking about with "AJAX".  Are you expecting the browser to display the file, or prompt the user to download, or something else?  It's not obvious (to me) why you'd want to serve PDF data in response to an XHR.

Comment: How do you expect to serve a PDF with an ajax request? You're not trying to output the content to a web page are you?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies. I'm trying to prompt the user to download the pdf file. Perhaps I need to do something on the AJAX side... (added AJAX to OP).

Comment: Don't do it with AJAX.  I'll edit my answer to add some headers that will instruct the browser to treat the file as a download.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't use XHR (Ajax), just link to a script like the one below.  The HTTP headers the script outputs will instruct the browser to download the file, so the user will not navigate away from the current page.

```
<?php
// "sendfile.php"

//remove after testing - in particular, I'm concerned that our file is too large, and there's a memory_limit error happening that you're not seeing messages about.
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

$file = '/home/eamorr/sites/eios.com/www/cvs/'.$cv;

//check sanity and give meaning error messages
// (also, handle errors more gracefully here, you don't want to emit details about your
//  filesystem in production code)
if (! file_exists($file)) die("$file does not exist!");
if (! is_readable($file)) die("$file is unreadable!");

//dump the file
header('Cache-Control: public'); 
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="some-file.pdf"');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));

readfile($file);

?>
```

Then, simplify your javascript:

```
$('#getCurrentCV').click(function(){
     document.location.href="sendfile.php";
});
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that. Many thanks. Still getting gobbldy-gook on AJAX response. Want user to open a file.

Comment: @Eamorr you can't do that through Ajax

Comment: @Eamorr - updated now.  You don't want AJAX - it's wholly unecessary, and likely won't work at all (but I've never tried).

Comment: @timdev: I do want AJAX! How else can I serve a page if it's off the site's root directory?

Comment: @Eamorr serving a page off the site's root directory has nothing to do with Ajax. An Ajax request can't do anything that a normal request can't. You can take the Ajax URL, and send the user directly there using a link or `location.href`.

Comment: @Eamorr - You link to a php file in the site root, that sends appropriate headers, then echos the PDF data, just like I wrote in my answer.

Comment: @timdev - I'm using your code for the solution. Thanks ever so much! Took a few minutes for the penny to drop, but I get it now...

Answer (score 2):

How about using [readfile](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) instead?  Provided that the file exists, that should work.  Make sure your web process has permission to read the directory and the file.  There is an example on the readfile page that sets some headers as well.

Comment: What would `readfile()` do better than `file_get_contents()`?

Comment: Hi, I did a readfile, but please bear in mind that this is an ajax request. The response is a gobbldy-gook text version of my pdf file. I want to return the file itself, not a text representation of it!

Comment: @Pekka It just takes the "convert to string" out of the equation, since that's not being used in this case anyway.  @Eamorr I missed that you were doing this as an AJAX request.  If you just try a normal HTTP request to this page (e.g., type the address in the URL bar), do you get the PDF then?

Comment: @Eamorr that gobbldy-gook is probably the PDF source code, that sounds fine. What are you doing with Ajax?

Comment: The gobbldy-gook is indeed the PDF source. I guess it's something on the AJAX side. I'm not doing anything with it right now... Not sure what to do.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to prompt the user to download the pdf file.

You can't (and don't need to) send a binary download to the user's browser using Ajax. You need to send the user to an actual URL where the PDF is located.

Use @timdev's code, and point the user there using e.g.

```
location.href = "scriptname.php";
```

Comment: @Eamorr it doesn't have to. Just take the Ajax URL and do a normal redirect to it instead of an Ajax request

Comment: Woop-woop1 It's working now! I put an <a href="./ajax/getCV.php">My CV</a> and it serves a file off of ../cvs

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're trying to serve the pdf to user for download via AJAX.

What you want to do is use AJAX to confirm the files exists, and security if any, then simply use js to redirect the browser to that files url, or in this case the url of the php script delivering the pdf. When your browser gets the pdf header it wont try to redirect the page itself but prompt for download, or whatever the users browser settings are.

Something like:
(js)

```
window.location.href = http://example.com/getApdf.php?which=xyz
```

(php)

```
if( !isset( $_GET['which'] ) ) die( 'no file specified' );
if( !file_exists( $_GET['which'] . '.pdf' ) ) die( 'file doesnt exist');

header('Content-type: application/pdf');

readfile( $_GET['which'] . '.pdf' );
```